# How to regenerate php-fpm sockets

Tags: php, unix-socket, php-8.1

I have a server running Apache 2.4 and php 8.1 with FPM for several virtual domains, and just now I noticed one of these domains is missing it's fpm socket in /var/php-fpm... Been googling how to regenerate these files with no luck, or I just missed the solution...
restarting FPM didn't work, neither did rebooting the server..., any help will be greatly appreciated!

Tried restarting FPM and rebooting the server

EDIT: Noticed my question could use some details:

This is an excerpt from my apache conf file where the sock is required (right now I'm using the fcgi):

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/php-fpm/167053454140818.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>
```

Inside my /var/php-fpm/ I can see all the other sockets for all my other virtual hosts which are 7, just not the one for this host in particular...

Comment: Stackoverflow has many communities. Maybe asking this in a community about UNIX or server will give you more solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The solution is very simple, for reasons unknown the file "/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/167053454140818.conf" associated with the virtual host in question had been corrupted. I manually deleted it and created a new one by copying another one from the other virtual hosts and changing the corresponding values, restarted php8.1-fpm and voilà, all good.